# Cannot find bluetooth devices. Atheros [0cf3:817b]

Tags: bluetooth, atheros

I am using a DELL Precision M4800.

When searching for bluetooth devices using "bluetooth-wizard", it just scans, but cannot find anything. Running "hcitool scan" won't find anything, too.

lspci

```
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0cf3:817b Atheros Communications, Inc. 

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev d4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Wilocity Ltd. Wil6200 PCI Express Root Port (rev 04)
04:00.0 PCI bridge: Wilocity Ltd. Wil6200 PCI Express Port (rev 04)
04:02.0 PCI bridge: Wilocity Ltd. Wil6200 Wireless PCI Express Port (rev 04)
04:03.0 PCI bridge: Wilocity Ltd. Wil6200 Wireless PCI Express Port (rev 04)
05:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
15:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0cf3:817b Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0c45:64d0 Microdia 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

hcitool dev

```
Devices:
    hci0    44:39:C4:59:A1:BD
```

Comment: This device is not supported yet. And Ubuntu 15.10 is off-topic here. I suggest reporting a but by running `ubuntu-bug linux`. You can drop here a link to the bug report. I will try to fix it.

Comment: Ok, here you are: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1506615

Comment: The bounty will go to Pilot6, no more answers needed! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ubuntu 14.04, 15.04 and 15.10 this can be fixed by a custom module. I've sent a patch upstream and it will be fixed in the official kernels some time.

Now you can install the module by running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/bluetooth
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install btusb-lp1506615-dkms
```

After you install the module power off the laptop, not just reboot. After that the bluetooth should work.

Also it makes sense to enable bluetooth and wireless coexistence by running:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf <<< "options ath9k btcoex_enable=1"
```

This will fix lags or disconnects when using Wi-Fi and bluetooth at the same time. It will be applied after reboot.

Comment: Can you post me  a link, so I can follow the progress?

Comment: Which link? Everything is there in the bug report.